# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _DhcpEnumServers on Win32 Build but okay on X64 build?

Tags: winapi

This is strange to me.  I have a project that builds fine with x64 Platform (both debug/release) but fails with the following on Win32 Platform (both debug/release):

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _DhcpEnumServers

The call looks like:

```
LPDHCP_SERVER_INFO_ARRAY pserverinfoarray = NULL;
DWORD dwerror = DhcpEnumServers(0, NULL, &pserverinfoarray, NULL, NULL);
```

It uses `#pragma comment(lib, "Dhcpsapi.lib")` - I also tried rebuilding (there was a recent update to visual studio 2022).

I build using visual studio 2022 on Win10 x64.

Any idea what it may be?

Comment: It may be a bug in the SDK shipped libraries. You're having the same problem as this https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/some-dns-api-functions-cause-lnk2019-errors-in-32/1191345 You can fix it by changing project's compile options to specify the /Gz switch: Project Properties->C/C++->Advanced->Calling Convention=__stdcall (/Gz).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it was.  I copied over the .h to local project, renamed, added `DHCP_API_FUNCTION` to the functions missing it (to many other libraries using `_cdecl` that I figured it would cause an issue to force `stdcall`) .